# javascript image object not work in chromica

Tags: javascript, image, object

I want to get width of an external image with javascript.

I try this code :

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "1.jpg";

alert(image.width);
```

but it get image width in firefox and get 0 in chrome.

why it not work in chromica?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
image.onload = function() {alert(this.width);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the width before the image has been downloaded. You have to wait, e.g.:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    alert(image.width);
};
image.src = "1.jpg";
```

Note that it's important to hook `onload` **before** you set `src`, because otherwise you have a race condition. Even though JavaScript is single-threaded on browsers (unless you use web workers), the *browser* is not. It can fire the `load` event as soon as you set `src` and, seeing no handlers, not queue them for callback.

Comment: Good to know the note part. Thanks TJ!